# How Auto Complete in java works with Reflection?

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection, autocomplete

I have heard that Eclipse uses reflection to provide its auto complete features.But How does it work actually?I searched Google but found no good article on it.Can Anyone please explain the procedures or provide me with any useful article on it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't use reflection. It uses the [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: +1 ,Thanks.That was exactly what I was searching.Still is it achievable with reflection?Want to know just for my curiosity.

Answer (score 5):

The reflection APIs can only tell you about code that is running (or at least, it is loaded within a program, in a complete compiled state, ready to run). When you're editing your code, it's not running, and it's not loaded into a JVM, so it can't possibly be examined using reflection. There is also information in Eclipse's auto-complete that is never available via reflection, such as names of local (within-method) variables.

Instead, Eclipse has its own compiler. It reads the source code directly and uses this to build its own understanding of the available classes, methods, constructors, fields and local variables. That information is used by several editing features including auto-complete.

Additionally, when the source code is not available, Eclipse can get partial information for auto-complete by reading compiled .class files directly. The .class file structure [is fully documented.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html) (There are several reasons why this is only "partial" information. For one thing, it does not include information about local variables if the class was compiled without debugging information. It also does not typically include the names of method parameters. (Java 8 has added a new "MethodParameters" attribute in the class file format which can be used to record the method parameter names, but javac does not do this by default.))

I'm no expert on Eclipse's internals but I think/hope this is accurate.