# Is it possible to import a library as source code, or do I have to compile it to JAR first?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I downloaded an open source Java library that is distributed as source code (Apache Crunch). I want to include it in my Intellij Idea project, as source code, and have the classes available to my code (including auto-completion etc).

Is this possible? Or do I have to compile the library to JAR first?

Answer (score 0):

I think auto-completion works with java's reflection API (at least for eclipse). The IDE need to have the class compiled and loaded in his classpath to be able to use reflection method on the class.
Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959100/how-auto-complete-in-java-works-with-reflection) can help